# how to append log in to text file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to write all log message in to text file. How can i write all logs in to text file if it is empty and if already have some data then append new log messages at the end of file.

How may i achieve this.

```
  NSString* loggerFileName = nil;
    loggerFileName = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"Logger" ofType:@"txt"];
NSMutableString *logger = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Loggers maintain here"];

    [logger appendFormat:@"\nCurrent user id is $: %@",UserID];
    NSLog(@"logger contains...*** : %@",logger);


    [logger writeToFile:loggerFileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];
```

By using above code, I can write to file but i am not able to append more logs on same text file.

Help me how may i do this. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Vikas s.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an NSString category method that will append the receiver to the specified path with the specified encoding (normally NSUTF8StringEncoding).

```
- (BOOL) appendToFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;
{
    BOOL result = YES;
    NSFileHandle* fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    if ( !fh ) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
        fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    }
    if ( !fh ) return NO;
    @try {
        [fh seekToEndOfFile];
        [fh writeData:[self dataUsingEncoding:enc]];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        result = NO;
    }
    [fh closeFile];
    return result;
}
```